# rand() and sorting do not work as expected in C from thenewboston tutorial 41

Tags: c

I have been following the [tutorial of thenewboston for C](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=14). I have some trouble getting it working like it should from the tutorial.

**There's two main issues:**

- The rand() function is outputing the same random numbers each time I
  run the program.
- The sorted list is just the same numbers repeating itself.

**The code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i, temp, swapped;
    int howMany = 10;
    int goals[howMany];

    for (i=0; i<howMany; i++) {
        goals[i] = ( rand()%25 ) + 1;
    }

    printf("Original List\n");

    for (i=0; i<howMany; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", goals[i]);
    }

    while(1) {
        swapped = 0;

        for (i=0; i<howMany-1; i++) {
            if (goals[i]>goals[i+1]) {
                temp = goals[i];
                goals[i] = goals[i+1];
                goals[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }

        if (swapped==0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\nSorted List\n");

    for (i=0; i<howMany; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", goals[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of `rand` & co. And get a new tutorial - better a goo C book.

Comment: @Olaf: Alright, but how about the repeated numbers of the sorted list? That does not make any sense.

Comment: `printf("%d \n", goals[1]);` - you don't see something wrong with that ? (hint: what is the index you're using?)

Comment: Please read the [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/398ax69y.aspx) where there is an example showing what to do, at the top of `main`.

Comment: Hahaha, omg. That's probably the worst typo ever. Thanks though @WhozCraig

Comment: As for `srand` omitting that is one of the most FAQ here. Sorry I didn't watch the video to see if they mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a simple mistake where you must use the variable `i` instead of a constant. If I change your code and use the variable instead of the constant, then the code works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, temp, swapped;
    int howMany = 10;
    int goals[howMany];

    for (i=0; i<howMany; i++) {
        goals[i] = ( rand()%25 ) + 1;
    }

    printf("Original List\n");

    for (i=0; i<howMany; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", goals[i]);
    }

    while(1) {
        swapped = 0;

        for (i=0; i<howMany-1; i++) {
            if (goals[i]>goals[i+1]) {
                temp = goals[i];
                goals[i] = goals[i+1];
                goals[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }

        if (swapped==0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\nSorted List\n");

    for (i=0; i<howMany; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", goals[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
$ ./a.out 
Original List
9 
12 
3 
16 
19 
11 
12 
18 
25 
22 

Sorted List
3 
9 
11 
12 
12 
16 
18 
19 
22 
25
```

If you don't know this, you should learn about loops and how a loop index works.